# How to revert to content of a Dijit text box when browser back-button is clicked?

Tags: python, dojo, textarea, back-button

I am using a Dojo Textarea Dijit to input and submit text (to be processed).

I found that after submiting, if a browser back-button is pressed (IE8, Firefox) unlike regular HTML Textarea, I return to the input screen, but the Textarea is EMPTY.

What I would like to happen is that after back-button is pressed, I would return to the previous page WITH the previously written text already in the Textarea - so that I can edit it, instead of writing it all again.

Can anyone explain how I do that (and some specific code example would be appreciated).

Thanks,
Barry.

Comment: What version are you using?  Can you provide a code snippet of how you are declaring your textarea?